# Uploading image filename or path to match an existing record in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a project that's almost completed but I added some code to upload images, the upload works fine but what's not working is sending the filepath to database, how do I go about it?

This is the Controller:

```
<?php
class Doctor extends Admin_Controller
{

    public function __construct ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('doctor_m');
    }

    public function index ()
    {
        // Fetch all doctors
        $this->data['doctors'] = $this->doctor_m->get();

        // Load view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/doctor/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }


    public function edit ($id = NULL)
    {
        // Fetch a doctor or set a new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['doctor'] = $this->doctor_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['doctor']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'doctor could not be found';
        }
        else {
            $this->data['doctor'] = $this->doctor_m->get_new();
        }

        // Set up the form
        $rules = $this->doctor_m->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        // Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $temp = $this->doctor_m->do_upload();

            //$data['userfile'] = "'".$temp."'";
            //$data['userfile'] = $this->doctor_m->array_from_post(array('userfile'));
            //dump($data);
            $data = $this->doctor_m->array_from_post(array('fullname', 'email', 'specialization', 'qualifications', 'publications', 'userfile'));
            $this->doctor_m->save($data, $id);
            redirect('admin/doctor');
        }

        // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/doctor/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }

    public function delete ($id)
    {
        $this->doctor_m->delete($id);
        redirect('admin/doctor');
    }
}
```

This is the Model:

```
<?php
class Doctor_m extends MY_Model {

    var $img;
    protected $_gallery_path;
    protected $_table_name = 'doctors';
    protected $_order_by = 'fullname desc, id desc';
    public $rules = array(
        'fullname' => array(
            'field' => 'fullname',
            'label' => 'Full Name',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
        ),      
        'specialization' => array(
            'field' => 'specialization',
            'label' => 'Specialization',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'        
        ),
        'publications' => array(
            'field' => 'publications',
            'label' => 'Publications',
            'rules' => 'trim|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
        ),
        'qualifications' => array(
            'field' => 'qualifications',
            'label' => 'Qualifications',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
        ),
        'userfile' => array(
            'field' => 'userfile',
            'label' => 'Userfile',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|xss_clean'
        ),
    );


    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public_html/img/doctor_image');
    }

    public function do_upload() {
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|JPG',
            'upload_path' => $this->_gallery_path,
            'max_size' => 2000,
            'remove_spaces' => true,
            'overwrite' => true,
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_error());

        } else {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $this->img = $image_data['full_path'];
        }

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $this->img,
            'new_image' => $this->_gallery_path . '/thumbs',
            'create_thumb' => true,
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 75,
            'height' => 50,
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $this->img,
            'maintain_ratio' => false,
            'width' => 400,
            'height' => 300,
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        return $image = $this->img;
    }

    public function get_new() {
        $doctor = new stdClass();
        $doctor->fullname = '';
        $doctor->specialization = '';
        $doctor->publications = '';
        $doctor->qualifications ='';    
        $doctor->email =''; 
        $doctor->userfile = '';
        return $doctor;
    }

    public function save_image() {

    }
}
```

This is the View:

```
<h3><?php echo empty($doctor->id) ? 'Add a new doctor' : 'Edit doctor'. " " . $doctor->fullname; ?></h3>

<?php echo validation_errors();?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart(); ?>
<?php// echo form_close(); ?>       
<?php// echo form_open();?>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Doctor's Image</td>
            <td>
                <?php
                    echo form_upload('userfile');
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('fullname', set_value('fullname', $doctor->fullname)); ?></td>    
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $doctor->email)); ?></td> 
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td>Specialization</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('specialization', set_value('specialization', $doctor->specialization)); ?></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Qualifications</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('qualifications', set_value('qualifications', $doctor->qualifications)); ?></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Publications</td>
            <td><?php echo form_input('publications', set_value('publications', $doctor->publications)); ?></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('upload', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>    
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: automatically CI will look for the paths on the root folder, where the `index.php` is located so a simple './public_html/img/doctor_image' will do the trick.

Comment: I know how to get the file path and how to use it but what I don't seem to be getting right is how to get the file path into the database, and the filepath should be attached to the doctor who own's the image.